# ASP.Net Core MVC Referential Partial Views Referencing Parent View Models

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I'm trying to create some reusable components in an ASP.Net Core MVC on Net 7.   I can't seem to figure out how to create a main page/view with partial views embedded that reference the main pages model.

So where I have a class something like the following as the @model for my main page...

```
public class MyMainModel
{
   string Property1;
   string Property2;
   List<string> Property3 = new List<string>();

}
```

I want that main page, Index.cshtml for example, to have a partial view that manages the Property3 on the Index.cshtml.

So far, it seems like PartialViews, ViewComponents, etc, all function in a way that they clone the object passed to them.  So any updates made by the PartialView or ViewComponent never make it back to the Index.cshtml pages @model.

So if I pass the list of Property3 over to a PartialView or ViewComponent, the cloned List does get updated, but it's not updating Propery3 @model of the Index.cshtml.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class MyMainModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Property3 { get; set; }          
}
```

Main View

```
@model MyMainModel
<form asp-action="Update" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Property1" />
    <input asp-for="Property2" />
    <partial name="_partial" for="@Model.Property3" />
    <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" />
</form>
```

Partial View

```
@model List<string>
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
{
    <input asp-for="@Model[@i]" name="Property3[@i]" type="text"/>
}
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = new MyMainModel()
    {
        Property1 = "aa",
        Property2 = "bb",
        Property3 = new List<string>() { "p1", "p2" }
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update([FromForm]MyMainModel model)
{
    //do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: I see. I'll give that a shot.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi @RobK. , Fine. Pls remember to give me the feedback if any update.

Comment: This lead me down a path where I eventually came to understand that so long as your PartialView builds out a naming and id path that matches up to the Parent pages model, it all hooks up referentially.